# Calculating average variance extracted (AVE) in R for checking discriminant validity (Fornell-Larcker criterion)

Tags: r, structural-equation-modeling, confirmatory-factor

We are using `lavaan` in `R` to calculate CFAs (confirmatory factor analyses) and SEMs (structural equation models). We now want to test whether two latent constructs can be assumed to be unrelated (discriminant validity).

Refering to

> Fornell, C. & Larcker, D. F. (1981). Evaluating structural equation models with unobservable variables and measurement error. Journal of Marketing Research, 18, 39–50.

we need to calculate the so called average variance extracted (AVE).

I found the following [R-help-mailing list post](https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-help/2011-December/299253.html). However, I don't think the output is the AVE I need for the Fornell-Larcker criterion. Values are calculated for each item and not factors.

Does anybody know how to obtain this value within `lavaan` or any other package?

If it is not possible to automatically obtain the AVE for each construct, can somebody point out how to calculate it based on the `lavaan` output?

Help would be much appreciated! Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As it seems the `semTools` package now provides a function that calculates the AVE based on a model estimated in `lavaan`:

`reliability()`

However, the package description notes that the calculation slightly differs from the one proposed in Fornell & Larcker (1981):

```
"Note that this formula is modified from Fornell & Larcker (1981) 
 in the case that factor variances are not 1."
```

I am not quite sure what this means for interpretation of the AVE.

Comment: To answer the post from phx, in the `reliability` function in semTools, I have adjusted the formula such that it is not sensitive to scale identification. That is, if you use the marker-variable approach for scale identification, the average variance extracted should remain the same as other identification methods.

Comment: I just checked the code. The calculation was wrong. I have updated the development version. See the details how to install the development version in wiki:

https://github.com/simsem/semTools/wiki

Comment: Sorry, @Sunthud, we (specifically the moderators) have to convert it for you; new users aren't allowed to comment until their reputation is >50. (This is to protect the site from spam.) We would love to have you as a member, & I'm sure you could reach 50 quickly. If you'd like to be more active, you may want take our [tour](http://stats.stackexchange.com/tour), which has information for new users.

Comment: I just mailed with Sunthud. Since he has not enough reputation to comment yet here his answer concerning the bug: simply change the following line: `avevar[j] <- mean(trueitem / (trueitem + erritem))` in the `semTools::reliability` function to `avevar[j] <- sum(trueitem) / sum(trueitem + erritem)`. The bug has not been fixed till 4 days ago.

Answer (score 1):

I developed a function to calculate CR and AVE for the sem package. I am sure you can adapt to lavaan.

Code follows:

```
crave <- function(model, digits=2) {
# ig111207
# computes composite reliability and average variance extracted
# usage: crave(model)
# where model is a sem fitted model
# such as sem.wh.1
require(sem)
x <- stdCoef(model, twoheaded=F)
coeff <- x[,2]
paths <- as.character(x[,3])
newl <- strsplit(paths, " <--- ")
newl <- as.data.frame(newl)
newl <- t(newl)
item <- newl[,1]
LV <- newl[,2]

coeff2 <- coeff^2
e2 <- 1-coeff2

y <- data.frame(LV, item, coeff, coeff2, e2)
rownames(y) <- item

cr <- by(y, LV, function(x) sum(x$coeff)^2 / (sum(x$coeff)^2+sum(x$e2)) )
    ave <- by(y, LV, function(x) sum(x$coeff2) / (sum(x$coeff2)+sum(x$e2)) )

z <- data.frame(
  cr=round(as.numeric(cr), digits),
  s1=ifelse(cr<.7,"","*"),
  ave=round(as.numeric(ave), digits),
  s2=ifelse(ave<.5,"","*")
)  

#print(y,digits)
#print(z)
answer <- list(items=y,latent=z)
answer

}
```

I hope this helps.

Iuri.